# Running PHPUnit tests Yii Framework

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, yii

What possibilities are there to run unit tests with my Yii application?

So far, I have been testing them this way:

Open command prompt

```
> cd C:\WHEREVER MY APP IS\protected\tests

> phpunit unit/TestingTest.php
```

Now, I was wondering if there is another way. Im new to the testing world so to speak, but it seems to me that there must be a better way than running one by one all tests. Thanks for any tips, im sure the question is quite dumb! But maybe it turns out to be helpful to someone else out there.

**EDIT** *(based on @David Harkness comment)*
Ok, so now I know that when i do this

> phpunit C:\WHEREVER MY APP IS\protected\tests\unit

All the tests within my TestingTest.php file are execute. My problem now is that within that unit folder, I have TWO files, TestingTest.php and <strike>TestingTest2.php</strike> **Testing2Test.php**. Only the tests within the first one are executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `phpunit` in that directory without specifying a file? That's what I do for non-Yii-based projects, and I cannot imagine it would be any different with Yii.

Comment: @David Harkness, Edited my question!

Comment: We wrote a blog post on how to run automated PHP unit testing with Yii. 
See: http://geeks.appbackr.com/61971101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit by default will scan for all files named `<foo>Test.php`. That means that `TestingTest2.php` will be ignored. You can either rename the file to `Testing2Test.php`, use

```
phpunit C:\WHEREVER MY APP IS\protected\tests\unit\*.php
```

to locate the files (not sure this works though), or create a [`phpunit.xml` configuration file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) that specifies the filename pattern that must match your tests. However, just rename it so all the files end in `Test.php` and you'll be much happier.

I generally always `cd` into the root test directory--the one that contains `bootstrap.php` and `phpunit.xml`. That way I don't have to tell PHPUnit how to find those files since it always looks in the current directory.

Comment: That was exactly my problem! Convention over configuration! Thanks @David !!

Comment: You can run it from root folder of your project, option `-c protected\tests` tells the config path. To run all unit tests, `phpunit -c protected\tests protected\tests\unit`